# duplicate log entries in Python UDP syslog server from iptables

Tags: python, udp, iptables, rsyslog

I've implemented a basic remote syslog server in Python with the following code:

```
self.UDPsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
self.UDPsock.bind(self.addr)
self.UDPsock.settimeout(1)
while self.carryOn:
  try: 
    data = self.UDPsock.recv(self.buf)
    print data
  except socket.timeout:
    pass
```

I'm using this to receive log messages from my router (Tomato Shibby v108). I'm particularly interested in intercepting messages from my mobile so that I can create a "presence" script.

I originally tried the following iptable entry for testing:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.2.54 -m limit --limit 1/minute --limit-burst 1 -j LOG
```

This worked as expected and I would receive messages such as:

```
<12>Apr  1 21:51:47 kernel: IN=br0 OUT=ppp0 SRC=192.168.2.54 DST=17.158.8.77 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23055 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=60779 DPT=993 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 MARK=0x5
```

However, I don't want to rely on a static IP, so changed the iptable filter to trigger on the MAC address:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source SOURCE_MAC -m limit --limit 1/minute --limit-burst 1 -j LOG --log-ip-options
```

The problem here was that I now received >50 messages per log entry, all duplicates of the form:

```
<12>Apr  1 19:54:00 kernel: IN=br0 OUT= MAC=DEST_MAC:SOURCE_MAC:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.54 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=101 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=36530 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=81
```

When I changed the filter to:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source SOURCE_MAC -m limit --limit 1/minute --limit-burst 1 -j LOG
```

It reduced the number of duplicates to 4:

```
<12>Apr  2 12:21:55 kernel: IN=br0 OUT= MAC=DEST_MAC:SOURCE_MAC:08:00 SRC=192.168.2.54 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=101 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=1384 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=81
```

Can anyone offer any insight as to why this is happening? I'm assuming there is some sort of "funny" character that is causing this. Can I alter either the iptable entry or the Python program to only receive a single log entry per message?